# Non coherence of Fermions and Bosons through $U(1)$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, group-theory, superposition, coherence

I *"know"* the textbook answer why we cannot write,

$$
|\psi\rangle = a|j=\tfrac{1}{2}\rangle + b|j=1\rangle
$$
as *"each term in the quantum superposition transforms differently under $U(1)$"*,
$$
U(2\pi)\ |\psi\rangle = -a|j=\tfrac{1}{2}\rangle + b|j=1\rangle
$$
and *"hence the phase difference is unobservable"*...

However, I do not understand what is meant by the italicised parts.

**Why is it that we cannot observe the phase difference?**

The question has arisen from studying notes on a course in *Symmetries of Quantum Mechanics* focusing on the group theoretical basis of QM.

Comment: If we define the phase difference $\Delta$ then under a rotation of $2\pi$ I would deduce that we obtain a new phase difference $\Delta'$. Is the answer based in this?

Comment: Think I have a resolution: Set up a superposition of two normalised wave functions $|\psi\rangle = |\phi_f\rangle + |\phi_b\rangle$ where $|\phi_b\rangle$ is bosonic and $|\phi_f\rangle$ is fermionic. Taking the inner product (up to a constant), $\langle\psi| \psi\rangle \propto \langle\phi_b|\phi_b\rangle + \langle\phi_f|\phi_b\rangle + \langle\phi_b|\phi_f\rangle + \langle\phi_f|\phi_f\rangle$ since the wave functions are normalised, $\langle\phi_b|\phi_b\rangle = \langle\phi_f|\phi_f\rangle = 1$ and they are orthogonal so $\langle\phi_b|\phi_f\rangle = \langle\phi_f|\phi_b\rangle = 0$.

Comment: Hence, $\langle\psi| \psi\rangle \propto 1-1+0+0 = 0$. Would welcome any better answers though!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the prototypical example of a *[superselection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superselection) rule*.

The operator $U(2\pi)$ commutes with all observables (because it represents a full rotation, and is hence physically a "do nothing" operator), and yet is not a multiple of the identity (because it is -1 on the fermionic and 1 on the bosonic parts of the Hilbert space). Therefore, the representation of the algebra of observables is reducible by [Schur's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur's_lemma), and the invariant subspaces are precisely the bosonic and fermionic subspaces.

Because the bosonic and fermionic subspaces (let's call them $H_b,H_f$) are invariant, all cross matrix elements for all observables vanish: $\langle b\vert A \vert f\rangle = 0$ for all $\lvert b\rangle\in H_b,\lvert f \rangle \in H_f$ and all observables $A$.

From this we can directly see that relative phases between bosonic and fermionic states are unobservable: For any $\lvert \psi \rangle = \lvert b\rangle + \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\phi}\lvert f\rangle$, $\langle \psi \vert A \vert \psi\rangle$ is independent of $\phi$, so there is no possible way to determine such relative phases experimentally - they are "unobservable".

Comment: Eloquently phrased. This links in everything I have been studying relevant to the question as well.

Comment: I particularly like the comment *"they are 'unobservable'."* ... It seems as though the throwaway comments in many notes on this subject stating that these states *"cannot exist"* or that they correspond to *"nonsense"* is, in fact, not exact. In contrast, what you state is more precise: That they simply cannot correspond to real  observable quantities.