# Does the generator of the group need to be physical observables?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, group-theory, lie-algebra, observables

In the Class, We have been told that the compact groups like $SO(3)$ have hermitian generators. Now in $SO(3)$, these generators turn out to be angular momentum components apart from some dimensions. The angular momentum is physical observables and this makes sense because these are hermitian as needed.

Now the translation in the Poincare group is not compact so it need not be that the generator is hermitian but the momentum which is the generator of translation happens to be Hermtian. Now since momentum is physically observable and therefore it makes sense that for it to be Hermitian.

Now Suppose we find a group that is not compact and hence has a non-hermitian generator, Is it possible for it to be physically observable also? But that's not possible because in quantum mechanics observable have hermitian operator only. How we can eliminate the possibility to have an only a non-hermitian generator in group theory?

I think, The question is not a very precise phrased, So If you don't get it, Please comment.

Answer (score 1):

No, a group generator could e.g. be associated with an unobservable gauge direction. See also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/373357/2451) related Phys.SE post.